# UWP Crashes all coming from ComCallHelper

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-app-center

My UWP app has recently began crashing and the majority of the crashes are related to the ComCallHelpers. I am using AppCenter to collect data about the crashes but all of the data is largely unhelpful:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.  Cannot create instance of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas' [Line: 0 Position: 0]

And the more generic:

> System.Exception: Unspecified error Unspecified error

Errors with parameters?

> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. element

From my research I've found recommendations to Cache the page correctly, however the InkCanvas is located inside a Grid inside a UserControl inside a FlipView.

Crashes occur on Windows 10.0.18362, 10.0.18363, 10.0.17763

Any details on how to debug these errors would be helpful.

Comment: Does above exception thrown in debug model?

Comment: I do see failures while debugging. When I see those crashes it breaks out of Visual Studio 2019 and asks to attach a new debugger. Not a typical app crash. Also it doesn't crash regularly or consistently.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT are there any more suggestions for how I can debug these errors?